# Pressing Ctrl+C during UPDATE query in Postgres, was the query partially run?

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally launched unwanted UPDATE query inside psql (9.4) and killed it with CTRL+C a few seconds later. Were there any records modified, or it's all or nothing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A statement is always atomic. That is true for all DML statements and nearly all DDL statements.

So either everything succeeds or nothing. If you interrupt it halfway through, everything that was changed until then will be rolled back.

Comment: DML? DDL? WDTM (what does that mean)?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @a_horse_with_no_name answer I can say that every statement you type in psql console is wrapped by `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` by default. And the same thing applies to single statements outside of any transaction block sent to postgres port.

So no, there is no way to perform action partly in postgres.

Also, you can adjust behavior of psql regarding `BEGIN;` and `END;` with adding this parameter to your `~/.psqlrc` file:

`\set AUTOCOMMIT off`

With this option turned off you'll need to manually `COMMIT` after every write statement which can help you avoid mistakes.